# SSL; FQDN of host different than internet-facing DNS - What CN to use for CSR?

Tags: ssl

I have service running a Windows box that users access via http from inside our network and from the internet. They access this service both via the browser and using a Desktop tool

The box's FQDN is **somebox.ourdomain.com**.

We're using DYNDNS so that external requests to **http://theservice.otherdomain.com** get our public IP. External users hit the service by accessing **http://theservice.otherdomain:8080**, and our router forwards to **somebox.ourdomain.com:80**

Works fine. But now we want to use SSL.

I'm a bit confused whether the CN I should use is the the FQDN of the host itself (somebox.ourdomain.com) OR that of the DNS entry (theservice.otherdomain.com). I suspect it's not the latter, as that would break for all of the internal folks.

Can someone confirm? Is this a scenario where it would be worth playing with a self-signed cert first to make sure I have the proper CSR values BEFORE I drop a couple hundred bucks on a CA signed cert?

Comment: I would recommend adding "theservice.otherdomain.com" to your internal DNS as well so you don't have to keep two URL's in your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CN of the certificate needs to be the fully qualified domain name that your clients will use to access the service.  For instance, if I access `bankaccounts.hugebank.com` from my PC, there will be a certificate issued for `bankaccounts.hugebank.com`.  More specifically, the subject of the certificate will be something like `CN=bankaccounts.hugebank.com, O=BigBank Inc, L=Detroit, S=Michigan, C=US`, even though the website itself is most likely not hosted on a single machine whose real hostname is bankaccounts.